# is it higher throughput to have multiple kafka consumers of the same consumer group within one JVM?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

imagine a simple application that consumes messages from a kafka topic that has 32 partition. It simply accumulates the messages into a List (imagine no OOM)

Consider the following two designs:

1. one kafka consumer, polls messages, addAll to the list.
2. 32 kafka consumers of the same group, polls at the same interval as case 1, and addAll to a threadsafe list.

which one of the design will lead to a faster growing list and why? Thanks.

Comment: if you have more cpu obviously second approach is the best one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One consumer thread would have to round-robin between 32 partitions in situation one.

If you have the available CPUs, then having 32 consumer threads, each reading as fast as they can with a 1-1 thread-partition mapping would be faster.

Rather than `addAll`, I would suggest trying to use a KTable, though. In Kafka Streams, you can just set `num.stream.threads=32`